# python upload files - error--device or resource busy

Tags: python, ubuntu

Im running python script to transfer files from local NFS shared ( mounted to my ubuntu server )  to remote ftp account , recenelty i faced this error alot and file stuck at upload stage , til i restart the script again ,

```
2015-04-06 14:00:16,360 -  - Error: OSError(16, 'Device or resource busy')
```

if there a way to debug or enable more logging during upload process to find out why this happen ?

My log def as following :

```
def initlogger(verbose):
        """ Logging function """
        fmt = '%(asctime)-15s - Upload - %(message)s'
        if verbose:
                logging.basicConfig(format=fmt,level=logging.DEBUG)
        else:
                logging.basicConfig(format=fmt,level=logging.INFO)
        logger = logging.getLogger('Upload')
        return logger
```

any thoughts

Regards

Comment: This is a filesystem problem, not a python issue. You would get the same issue when trying to browse the filesystem at the same time.

Comment: NFS  issue , not the destination server issue am i right !?  how i can over come this ? any clue ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea

Comment: with ftp you can turn on the hash command.  Inside of the remote ftp before you start the data pull (or push) use the hash command.  Then start the push/pull operation.   Then actively pump the console buffer and determine the number of bytes that are coming across.  You should be able to determine a rate.   Additional ideas.  Use passive ftp approach and open multiple streams (sockets) and get it across possibly quicker.  Alternatively don't use NFS.  Put the files on your local computer, then upload to FTP.  but still use the hash trick as you can then figure your xfer rate and recover.

Comment: You might want to run with strace and look at a lower level. it might tell you where the timeout is happening.   Or go look at the system logs.